# Cannot connect to MySQL database using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, pymysql

I have a Python program which is trying to connect to a MySQL 8.31 database. This is the code I am using.

```
    connection_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=%s;UID=root;PWD=password" % db_name
    connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
    engine = create_engine(connection_url)
    pd.read_sql('select * from apps_list', engine)
```

I get this exception

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001',
> '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes
> Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhJQM.png).  (2)
> (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
> Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17
> for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has
> occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not
> found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL
> Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information
> see SQL Server Books Online. (2)') (Background on this error at:
> https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

I have researched this exception and most people recommend using SQL Server Configuration manager which I do not seem to have on my system.

Not in Computer Management
[image]

Not in C:\Windows\SysWOW64
[image]

Others have said to ensure Named Pipes are allowed which they are
[image]

And finally I've ensured Ports 3306 and 1433 are open
[image]

Yet I still get this exception.

For the record I am able to connect using this code

```
mydb = pymysql.connect(
        host="localhost",
        database=db_name,
        user="root",
        password="****",
        autocommit=True

    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://****@localhost/%s' % db_name )
```

However this gives me a warning and tells me to use SQLAlchemy:

> userwarning: pandas only support SQLAlchemy
> connectable(engine/connection) ordatabase string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2
> connectionother DBAPI2 objects are not tested, please consider using
> SQLAlchemy warnings.warn(

I am slightly confused at this because I am using SQLAlchemy to create the connection on this line

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://****@localhost/%s' % db_name )
```

Is it fine the way I am currently connecting? Please let me know how I should connect.

Comment: I am confused. You are talking about connectin to MySQL 8 but using connectors for MsSQL server (DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}). Those DB are not the same and do not use the same drivers so that maybe the reason of your problems